# Joomla default template

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 Beez2 default template. I am adding new menus and articles but it bothers me that it already has its default menus and articles which i didn't need. Is there a way to delete all menus for example and create my own from scratch? or do i have to delete them one by one? And if i work around with this template and i want to back it to its setup setting before all changes were made? And is there any way to change the header background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take you no more than 5 minutes to delete all of the sample data or if you have not added any content you can (assuming this is not a live site drop all your tables and run joomla.sql o set up an empty site.

Comment: Excuse me i am very new in Joomla could you tell me in steps how i can delete samples data

Comment: Go to the article manager. Select all the articles. Click the delete button. Go to the articles category manager and select all (or possibly leave uncategorised). Click the delete button.  Go to the contact manager. Select all contacts. Click delete.  Go to the categories for contacts and select all or all but uncategorised, click the delete button. And so on.  
Then delete the menus you don't staring with the items, but leave one menu with the default menu items.